# Is there a way to embed an excel file with my executable (exe) file?

Tags: excel, vba, exe, autohotkey

I've created an AutoHotKey Executable file to open my macro enabled excel. I want to share only the exe file (not the excel file) to my peers. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure thing.  This is so easy.  Please refer to:

**FileInstall**:
Includes the specified file inside the compiled version of the script and writes it to Dest.

```
FileInstall, Source, Dest [, Overwrite]
```

at https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileInstall.htm

and lookit the example:

```
FileInstall, C:\My Documents\My File.txt, %A_ProgramFiles%\My Application\Readme.txt, 1
```

or

```
FileInstall, Make Dragon Commands - Copy.png, %Me%.png, 0
Gui, Add, Picture, , %Me%.png  ;  add a graphic
FileDelete, %Me%.png
```

to add a graphic to a gui.

Comment: This still shares the Excel file, which is what the question asks not to do.

Comment: Thank you PGilm. This is what I'm expecting. I got what i needed.

Comment: @KenWhite With FileInstall, Excel file is embedded with the AHK script itself. So I don't need to share the Excel file to my peers. So that I can only share the AHK exe file to open the excel file.